# Dirac sea for Majorana equation

Tags: antimatter, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

To resolve the problem of infinite energies, Dirac has proposed the conception of the Dirac sea. Is the same concept present for the case of Majorana spinors? How it is affected by the absence of antiparticles?

Comment: The Dirac sea is ultimately unphysical because in such a theory the energy spectrum is not bounded from below. Any state would decay infinitely into states of lower and lower energy. This is not what we observe. Divergences in QFT are nowadays mostly dealt with by means of renormalisation.

Comment: @ThomasWenimg : this one has nothing to do with my question. The Dirac sea is nothing but a kind of the Bogoliubov transformation of creation-annihilation operators 2with the rwmaining story about divergences.